# Detecting edges of bright spots

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an X-ray image of the circuit board and I am trying to segment some components and find voids inside them (voids are brights spots on the image). I successfully separated the component but I am having trouble to get a contour of the void. [image: Input image]

So far I found it using the laplace edge detector in combination with gaussian and median filter but there is still too much noise detected. How can I get rid of that? [image: My steps]

On first image you can see contours that I got using the OTSU threshold which is the best result so far but I don't think that it is a good approach because user can't affect the behavior anyhow because thresh value is calculated automatically. On top of that contours on this image are not surrounding whole void(white spots)

The images from 2 to 8 are steps of how I am modifying the image. I am using gaussian and median blur, that clahe enhancing that could cause a lot of noise, but even without it the result is basically the same. And the last step is Laplacian edge detector and morphological closing.

Is there any better approach?

Here are my input argumets:

```
            package.voids.contours, package.voids.hierarchy = self.find_voids_inside_component(
            cropped,
            clahe_clip_limit=1,
            clahe_tile_grid_size=(3, 3),
            laplacian_ksize=11,
            closing_ksize=2,
            closing_iterations=2,
            debug_mode=True,
            fxy=1)
```

And here is the function itself:

```
def find_voids_inside_component(self,
                                cropped,
                                clahe_clip_limit=2,
                                clahe_tile_grid_size=(3, 3),
                                laplacian_ksize=15,
                                closing_ksize=3,
                                closing_iterations=1,
                                debug_mode=False,
                                fxy=3):
    """
    This fuction calculates the ratio between the void area and the ball area
    :param fxy:
    :param closing_iterations:
    :param closing_ksize:
    :param laplacian_ksize:
    :param clahe_tile_grid_size:
    :param clahe_clip_limit:
    :param cropped:
    :param debug_mode: if True it will print additional info
    :return: contours, hierarchy
    """
    output.debug_show("Original image", cropped, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=False)


    # PARAM: Median blur before enhancing image
    # get rid of salt-and-pepper noise using the median filter
    median_blur = cv2.medianBlur(cropped, ksize=5)

    # debug print
    output.debug_show("Median blur 2", median_blur, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=False)

    # apply the smoothing
    # PARAM: The parameters of the Gaussian blur
    # ksize – Gaussian kernel size. ksize.width and ksize.height can differ but they both must be positive and odd.
    #         Or, they can be zero’s and then they are computed from sigma* .
    #
    # sigmaX – Gaussian kernel standard deviation in X direction.
    #
    # sigmaY – Gaussian kernel standard deviation in Y direction; if sigmaY is zero, it is set to be equal to
    #          sigmaX, if both sigmas are zeros, they are computed from ksize.width and ksize.height ,
    #          respectively (see getGaussianKernel() for details); to fully control the result regardless
    #          of possible future
    #         modifications of all this semantics, it is recommended to specify all of ksize, sigmaX, and sigmaY.
    #
    # borderType – pixel extrapolation method (see borderInterpolate() for details).
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(cropped, (5, 5), 0)

    # debug print
    output.debug_show("Gauss blur", blur, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=False)



    # improve the local contrast using CLAHE
    # create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional).
    # PARAM: Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization
    #  clipLimit – Threshold for contrast limiting.
    #  tileGridSize – Size of grid for histogram equalization. Input image will be divided into equally sized
    #                       rectangular tiles. tileGridSize defines the number of tiles in row and column.

    # good values (clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(3, 3))
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=clahe_clip_limit, tileGridSize=clahe_tile_grid_size)
    # it is allso possible to use gaussian blur
    cl1 = clahe.apply(median_blur)

    # debug print
    output.debug_show("Enhanced Image", cl1, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=False)

    # debug print -> convert gray scale to colormap
    color_map = cv2.applyColorMap(cl1, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    output.debug_show("Color map", color_map, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=False)


    # use some edge detector to get the contours of void
    # color_map = cv2.cvtColor(color_map, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # PARAM: The parameters of the Gaussian blur
    # ksize – Gaussian kernel size. ksize.width and ksize.height can differ but they both must be positive and odd.
    #         Or, they can be zero’s and then they are computed from sigma* .
    #
    # sigmaX – Gaussian kernel standard deviation in X direction.
    #
    # sigmaY – Gaussian kernel standard deviation in Y direction; if sigmaY is zero, it is set to be equal to
    #          sigmaX, if both sigmas are zeros, they are computed from ksize.width and ksize.height ,
    #          respectively (see getGaussianKernel() for details); to fully control the result regardless
    #          of possible future
    #         modifications of all this semantics, it is recommended to specify all of ksize, sigmaX, and sigmaY.
    #
    # borderType – pixel extrapolation method (see borderInterpolate() for details).
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(cl1, (5, 5), 0)

    # PARAM: Laplacian edge detector
    # ddepth – Desired depth of the destination image.
    # ksize – Aperture size used to compute the second-derivative filters. See getDerivKernels() for details.
    #        The size must be positive and odd.
    #
    # scale – Optional scale factor for the computed Laplacian values. By default, no scaling is applied.
    #        See getDerivKernels() for details.
    #
    # delta – Optional delta value that is added to the results prior to storing them in dst .
    #
    # borderType – Pixel extrapolation method. See borderInterpolate() for details.
    # ToDo: Try more edge detectors Solber, Canny
    # edges = cv2.Canny(blur,threshold1=50, threshold2=100)

    edges = cv2.Laplacian(median_blur, cv2.CV_8U, ksize=laplacian_ksize)
    # abs_edges64f = np.absolute(edges)
    # edges_8u = np.uint8(abs_edges64f)

    # debug print
    output.debug_show("Edges", edges, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=False)

    # use closing
    kernel = np.ones((closing_ksize, closing_ksize), np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=closing_iterations)

    # debug print
    output.debug_show("Closing", closing, debug_mode=debug_mode, fxy=fxy, waitkey=True)

    # get contours
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # print("Number of contours: ", len(contours))

    return contours, hierarchy
```

I am using Python 3 and OpenCV

Comment: What is the expected result for the given x-ray?

Comment: You could try **Difference of Gaussians**. I tried it out after applying *clahe* and it looks promising

Comment: It would be helpful if you attached the sample input as a usable image (i.e. not a screenshot of a window with rounded corners and a massive shadow around it).

Comment: what about user defined thresholding? Or Otsu with option to let the user change the threshold afterwards?How much user interaction do you want to allow? There are techniques where the user can select some coarse regions and fine segmentation is performed automatically.